# jQuery Isotpoe, adding item pushes all the way to down

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

I purchased a web template, but am having a hard time dynamically adding an element to the isotope container and the author is not responding for days now.

Here is the demo page of the template with isotope: http://freshfruits.us/acerola/index_scroll.html

If you please open your web console then paste this:

```
$items = $('.izotope-container').append('<div class="item web"><a href="#"></a><div class="det-img ellem" data-caption="hi"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CO1mT7yU8AI5eVG.png" alt=""></img></div></div>');
```

This will append an item to the file with a link to an image in one of my tweets.

The next step is I call `addItems with isotope:

```
$('.izotope-container').isotope('addItems', $items)
```

Now we have to update the isotope layout, and this is where all the items are pushed to the bottom:

```
$('.izotope-container').isotope('layout');
```

Why is this so? How can I fix it so it doesn't push everything way to the bottom creating a huge whitespace gap requiring user to scroll page all the way down?

Answer (score 0):

`addItems` does not lay out items like appended, prepended, or insert in isotope. If you want appended items to layout, try this:

```
$items = $('<div class="item web"><a href="#"></a><div class="det-img ellem" data-caption="hi"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CO1mT7yU8AI5eVG.png" alt=""></img></div></div>');

 $('.izotope-container').append( $items ).isotope( 'appended', $items );
```

Comment: I tried this too, it jacks up the formatting and pushes it all the way to the bottom, :( may you please try running the code there, you'll see what i mean, its totally mind boggling man.

Comment: Did you change your $items variable as in the answer? It can't have appended in it.It works for me